# How to create an Either[S,T] where S or T could be Unit?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

```
private def responseValidationFlow[T](responsePair: ResponsePair)(implicit evidence: FromByteStringUnmarshaller[T]) = responsePair match {
    case (Success(response), _) => {
      response.entity.dataBytes
        .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 8192))
        .mapAsyncUnordered(Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()) { body =>
          if (response.status == OK) {
            val obj: Future[T] = Unmarshal(body).to[T]
            obj.foreach(x => log.debug("Received {}: {}.", x.getClass.getSimpleName, x))
            obj.map(Right(_))
          } else {
            val reason = body.utf8String
            log.error("Non 200 response status: {}, body: {}.", response.status.intValue(), reason)
            Future.successful(reason)
              .map(Left(_))
          }
        }
    }
    case (Failure(t), _) => {
      Source.single(Left(t.getMessage))
    }
  }
```

What I’d like to do is parameterize both sides of the `Either`. That’s not hard to do, but what I’m having trouble with is creating a `Left` or `Right` that doesn’t have a value. In that case, the body should be consumed fully and discarded. I tried using `ClassTag`s, but the compiler thinks that the type is `Any`, not `S` or `T`. An sample invocation of this a method would look like `responseValidationFlow[String, Unit]` producing an `Source[Either[String, Unit]]`

Comment: Isn't that an `Option[String]`

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil Only if one of the types is `Unit`. Other times, it could be `Either[String, Whatever]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you can just define an implicit unmarshaller to `Unit` in scope:

```
implicit val unitUnmarshaller: FromByteStringUnmarshaller[Unit] = 
  Unmarshaller.strict(_ => ())
```

Comment: So you’re saying that I shouldn’t check for the type specifically, but depend on implicit and the compiler to do the conversion? I’ll try that and comment thereafter.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You wouldn't really depend on the implicit. In the question you've said, that you explicitly specify `Unit`, when you call `responceValidationFlow[Unit]`. So when you state that you want `Unit`, the compiler will use this implicit and discard the response body.

Comment: It doesn't work without the implicit evidence. I've posted an answer with the working code (it's too big for a comment). I'll accept your answer as you led me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @Kolmar suggested, here is the working code.

```
private def responseValidationFlow[L, R](responsePair: ResponsePair)(
  implicit ev1: FromByteStringUnmarshaller[L], ev2: FromByteStringUnmarshaller[R]
): Source[Either[L, R], Any] = {
  responsePair match {
    case (Success(response), _) => {
      response.entity.dataBytes
        .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 8192))
        .mapAsyncUnordered(Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()) { body =>
          if (response.status == OK) {
            val obj: Future[R] = Unmarshal(body).to[R]
            obj.foreach(x => log.debug("Received {}.", x.getClass.getSimpleName))
            obj.map(Right(_))
          } else {
            log.error("Non 200 response status: {}.", response.status.intValue())
            Unmarshal(body).to[L]
              .map(Left(_))
          }
        }
    }
    case (Failure(t), _) => {
      log.error(t, "Request failed.")
      Source.empty
    }
  }
}
```

If the method is invoked like this `responseValidationFlow[Status, Unit]`, then a `FromByteStringUnmarshaller[Unit]` is made available at call site. The compiler uses the `implicit` evidence to find the required `Unmarshaller`.